# Spring 4 : How to map RequestMapping URLs to particular controller

Tags: java, xml, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-4

I have written a Spring MVC application with multiple controllers.

On the JSP, I have the `action` on the form:

```
 <form id="createTableForm" method="post" name="createTable" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveTable" >
```

and the same action is mapped to a method in the Controller:

```
@Controller
public class TableController implements TableConstants {

  @RequestMapping(value="/saveTable")
  public String saveTable(HttpServletRequest request,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
  //...
  }
}
```

And in my `web.xml`:

```
  <context-param>
    <description>Context name of the Application</description>
    <param-name>contextName</param-name>
    <param-value>W****</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <description>Database used for</description>
    <param-name>databaseName</param-name>
    <param-value>w*****</param-value>
</context-param>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>FilterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.abc.w****.configuration.FilterChainProxy
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>FilterChainProxy</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>


<jsp-config>
    <taglib>
        <taglib-uri>http://displaytag.sf.net</taglib-uri>
        <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tld/displaytag.tld</taglib-location>
    </taglib>
</jsp-config>
```

Do I need to include the URL mapping to that particular Controller in the `web.xml` file or in the `WebAppConfig` class?

I have the `WebAppConfig` annotated with @Configuration, @ComponentScan and @EnableWebMVC.  It has the following methods:

```
 public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
 }
 public MessageSource messageSource() {
 }
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
 }
 public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() { 
 }
```

Please advise.

Comment: So you want to achieve that particular controller has its own URL mapping  too?

Comment: I want to know the correct approach as of now my Controller class is just annotated with @Controller annotation. So should we provide the URL mapping to Controller class and append that mapping to action in JSP as well with RequestMapping URL

Comment: post your servlet-config.xml

Comment: Add RequestMapping annotation to the controller.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Do you want your controller to have a URL so that your request URL, /saveTable,  is instead /foo/saveTable?

Answer (score 1):

The `@RequestMapping` annotation could be applied to the controller class. In this case all the methods in this class will derive the defaults from the class annotation and the implementation could override it.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple things you would need to do

1. In web.xml configure Spring's DispatcherServlet to intercept the request and direct it to the Controllers.For example to map DispatcherServlet to requests that at root, add following lines

   ```
   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. Make sure in the bean definition xml, you have configured component scan on the package that has your controllers so that Spring container can discover them.

Comment: No this guy is using annotations for configuration, there is no need to use web.xml.  Look at http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/WebApplicationInitializer.html and do the same thing without web.xml.